# ¿Suma de varias variables en PHP?

Tags: php

Sucede que tengo este código armado en una plataforma de Dreamwever, necesito hallar una manera para que todos los datos generados automáticamente por el comando "rand" se sumen en la casilla de "Totales", para ambas variables, tanto para x como para y. pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo

```
"<?php
if ( isset($_POST['calcular']) ) {
$numero = $_POST['numero'];
}else{
$numero = 0;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Documento sin t&iacute;tulo</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="200" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#00FF66">REGRESION LINEAL </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="50%" bgcolor="#666699"><div align="center">Numero</div></td>
  <td width="50%" align="center" bgcolor="#669966"><input name="numero" 
 type="text" id="numero" value="<?php echo $numero ; ?>" size="10" 
 maxlength="10" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#99FF00"><input name="calcular" type="submit" id="calcular" value="CALCULAR" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
<br />
<br />
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['calcular'])){
**$sumax = 1;
$sumay =2 ;
$sumaxy = 3 ;
$sumaxx = 4** ; (aqui puse 1,2,3,4. porque no se como definir la sumatoria total y no sabia que mas poner para que no me diera error el codigo)
$b=(($numero*$sumaxy)-($sumax*$sumay))/(($numero*$sumaxx)-($sumax*$sumax));
$a= ($sumay-($b*$sumax))/$numero ;

?>
<table width="800" border="1" align="center">
 <tr>
<td width="20%" align="center">Numero</td>
<td width="20%" align="center">X</td>
<td width="20%" align="center">Y</td>
<td width="20%" align="center">XY</td>
<td width="20%" align="center">X^2</td>
 </tr>
 <?php
 for($n=1; $n<=$numero; $n++){
 ?>
<tr>
<td width="20%" align="center"><?php echo $n; ?></td>
<td align="center">
<?php
 $x = rand(20,250);
 echo $x ;
?>  </td>
<td width="20%" align="center">
<?php
 $y = rand(20,210);
 echo $y ;
?>  </td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $x * $y ; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $x * $x ; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
}
?>
<tr>
<td align="center">Totales</td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $sumax ; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $sumay; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $sumaxy; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $sumaxx; ?></td>
```

```
</table>
<br />
<br />
<table width="400" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="center">A</td>
<td width="50%" align="center"><?php echo $a ; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="center">B</td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $b ; ?></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: y si mejor pones el código que estas usando?

Comment: Listo, lo siento es la primera vez que usaba esta plataforma

Answer (score 1):

Puedes guardar tus variables en un arreglo, y al final sumarlos en el total de cada fila utilizando [array_sum](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php), de esta manera:

```
<?php
$numero = 20;
?>
<table width="800" border="1" align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Numero</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">X</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Y</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">XY</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">X^2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $arregloDeX = [];
        $arregloDeY = [];
        $arregloDeXY = [];
        $arregloDeXX = [];

        for($n=1; $n <= $numero; $n++):
            // Generamos los números para X y Y y calculamos los demas valores
            $x = rand(20,250);
            $y = rand(20,210);
            $xy = $x * $y;
            $xx = pow($x, 2);

            // Guardamos las variables en arreglos para luego sumarlos
            $arregloDeX[] = $x;
            $arregloDeY[] = $y;
            $arregloDeXY[] = $xy;
            $arregloDeXX[] = $xx;

        ?>
        <tr>
            <?php // Desplegamos los valores generados en cada iteración ?>
            <td><?php echo $n ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $x ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $y ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $xy ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $xx ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        endfor;
        ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <?php // Desplegamos las sumas de todas las columnas ?>
            <td>Totales</td>
            <td><?php echo array_sum($arregloDeX) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo array_sum($arregloDeY) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo array_sum($arregloDeXY) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo array_sum($arregloDeXX) ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

---

Un resultado posible quedaría así (los valores cambiarán con cada ejecución):

```html
<table width="800" border="1" align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Numero</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">X</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Y</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">XY</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">X^2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>193</td>
            <td>122</td>
            <td>23546</td>
            <td>37249</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>158</td>
            <td>199</td>
            <td>31442</td>
            <td>24964</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>227</td>
            <td>154</td>
            <td>34958</td>
            <td>51529</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>249</td>
            <td>57</td>
            <td>14193</td>
            <td>62001</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>157</td>
            <td>169</td>
            <td>26533</td>
            <td>24649</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>157</td>
            <td>173</td>
            <td>27161</td>
            <td>24649</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>154</td>
            <td>6314</td>
            <td>1681</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>111</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>3219</td>
            <td>12321</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>3906</td>
            <td>3969</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>238</td>
            <td>155</td>
            <td>36890</td>
            <td>56644</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>196</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>19600</td>
            <td>38416</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>34</td>
            <td>71</td>
            <td>2414</td>
            <td>1156</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>132</td>
            <td>49</td>
            <td>6468</td>
            <td>17424</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>81</td>
            <td>98</td>
            <td>7938</td>
            <td>6561</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>60</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>2880</td>
            <td>3600</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>174</td>
            <td>196</td>
            <td>34104</td>
            <td>30276</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>178</td>
            <td>70</td>
            <td>12460</td>
            <td>31684</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>219</td>
            <td>132</td>
            <td>28908</td>
            <td>47961</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>244</td>
            <td>183</td>
            <td>44652</td>
            <td>59536</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>127</td>
            <td>25400</td>
            <td>40000</td>
        </tr>
            </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
                        <td>Totales</td>
            <td>3112</td>
            <td>2348</td>
            <td>392986</td>
            <td>576270</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```